# Does Google Wallet for Digital Goods support automated refunds?

Tags: google-api, payment-gateway, android-pay

Does this API *only* support payments from a buyer to the merchant and nothing else? It seems that this in-app purchase API has no support for programmatically handling refunds and cancellations.. I love the embedded experience, but I need a slightly more robust API to work with..

Looking at the Google Checkout API, it's clear that this allows order refunds programatically. However, it also looks that the merchantID (basically the API key) is not usable between Google Wallet for Digital Goods and Google Wallet for Checkout.

**Can Google Wallet for Digital Goods support programmatic refunds, and if not, can you still use the Digital Goods embedded payment experience with the Checkout API?**

Answer (score 1):

Google Wallet for Digital Goods API supports only purchases (https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference).

In relation of whether Wallet and Checkout APIs work together or not, an april 2012 post from a googler answering that question said

> Right now In-App refunds can be processed manually through the Merchant Center. 
>   As you point out, an automated refund solution is an important feature and it is on our todo list.

but AFAIK none of the Google Wallet API support cancellation/refunds as of now.

You might also want to consider:

> On November 20, 2013, Google Checkout will no longer be supported. If you process payments using Google Checkout, you will need to migrate to a new solution to avoid disruption to your business.

(https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing?hl=ro&csw=1#order_processing_api)